# cannot convert lambda expression to type string error in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a grid displaying some data in my aspx. This grid has a column like below:

```
columnBuilder.For(o => o.IsPrioritized)
                 .Attributes(style => "text-align:center")
                 .SortColumnName("IsPrioritized")
                 .Named("IsPrioritized");
```

I wanna show "yes" or "no" instead of "true" or "false". What I am trying is:

```
columnBuilder.For(o => o.IsPrioritized== true ? "yes" : "no" )
                     .Attributes(style => "text-align:center")
                     .SortColumnName("IsPrioritized")
                     .Named("IsPrioritized");
```

However, this is giving me the error below:

```
cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type aspx
```

Note that the IsPrioritized attribute is type of bool and I am not allowed to change its type to string. In this regard, how can I fix this error and provide the requested situation?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I checked the error message online but all the suggestions saying me to use "using System.Data.Entity". But it is aspx page, not server side. So couldnt do it.

Comment: Which grid are you using?

Comment: Html.Grid(Model.SearchResults.List)
                    .Columns(columnBuilder => ...